# unknown error (code 14): Could not open database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a working app which employs a database and [SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper). The database file (sql.sqlite) is zipped (sql.sqlite.zip) and put in the assets/databases folder.

The program works perfectly well. And when run for a second/third/fourth... time it starts up quickly. But if I do a "force stop" followed by a "clear data" then run it again, then when I run it (viewing logs) I see an error "unknown error (code 14): Could not open database"... but then I wait a few seconds and it all loads and works perfectly.

The log is as follows:

```
W/SQLiteAssetHelper(18393): could not open database SQL.sqlite - unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
W/SQLiteAssetHelper(18393): copying database from assets...
W/SQLiteAssetHelper(18393): extracting file: 'sql.sqlite'...
W/SQLiteAssetHelper(18393): database copy complete
I/SQLiteAssetHelper(18393): successfully opened database SQL.sqlite
```

So it looks like it somehow tried to find the database, failed, crashed, and then repaired itself. So my question is, how could I have avoided the clumsy start and the several seconds of delay?

**EDIT:** My first reference to the database in my code is...

```
public class Globals extends Application
{
    Custom_SQLiteAssetHelper db;   
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        db = new Custom_SQLiteAssetHelper(this);
        cursor = db.get_first_species_common_name();
```

and I have...

```
public class Custom_SQLiteAssetHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper
{
    public Custom_SQLiteAssetHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, "SQL.sqlite", null, 1);  
    }
    public Cursor get_first_species_common_name()
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        SQLiteQueryBuilder querything = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
            // etc...
```

Comment: The process is like you try to access a database first (with error), then you create it, and access it again. Guess you need to re-arrange the way you did it.

Comment: See edits to OP... maybe that'll be clearer.

Comment: You can try to use Context.getDatabasePath(dbName).exists() to determine whether your db is already there. As for the seconds of delay, I believe its because you have a big database which it takes time to unzip and copy. If it is because of unzip, don't zip it from the beginning. If it is copying that takes time, increase the number of bytes for each copy action it takes place.

Comment: Are you sure this is not "by design"? Other than a log message which just means it tried to access your database which isn't there and had to copy it, I'm not sure why you think this is a problem. As android devs we see log spam all the time. As haike00 mentions the delay is the unzip and copy

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. have you found the answer? @Mick

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have found the answer. you should use the [newer version of SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
super(context, "SQL.sqlite", null, 1);
```

with

```
 super(context, "SQL", null, 1);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public Custom_SQLiteAssetHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context, "SQL.sqlite", null, 1);  
}
```

Change to

```
public Custom_SQLiteAssetHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context, "SQL.sqlite", null, 1);  
    close();
}
```

@haike00 he is using SQLiteAssetHelper which is a library, it support you copy pre-filled sqlite database to internal/external storage when first run app. When using this lib, you have to zip your sqlite file, no other options.